# using for loop for s3 object in terraform fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

Here is the code producing this error:

```
locals {
  object_names = ["at", "in", "the", "we", "it"]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "subfolders" {
  depends_on = [module.dds_bucket]
  for_each = { for name in local.subfolder_names : name => name }

  bucket = "ea-dds-${var.app_environment}-store"
  key    = "${each.value}/"
  source = "/dev/null"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "out" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_object.subfolders]
  for_each = { for obj_key, obj in aws_s3_bucket_object.subfolders : for name in local.object_names : "${obj.key}${name}/" => { bucket = "ea-dds-${var.app_environment}-store", key = "${obj.key}${name}/", source = "/dev/null" } }

  bucket = each.value.bucket
  key    = each.value.key
  source = each.value.source
}
```

Error: Invalid 'for' expression

```
  on infra/s3.tf line 161, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "out":
 161:   for_each = { for obj_key, obj in aws_s3_bucket_object.subfolders : for name in local.object_names : "${obj.key}${name}/" => { bucket = "ea-dds-${var.app_environment}-store", key = "${obj.key}${name}/", source = "/dev/null" } }

Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression.
```

I am sure the loop is wrong but not sure how to correct it. tried several times without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to flatten your for loop for the `for_each`, which can be done using `merge`. It should be:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "out" {
  for_each = merge([for obj_key, obj in aws_s3_bucket_object.subfolders: {
                for name in local.object_names : 
                  "${obj.key}${name}/" => { 
                      bucket = "ea-dds-${var.app_environment}-store"
                      key = "${obj.key}${name}/"
                      source = "/dev/null" 
                  } 
              }]...)

  bucket = each.value.bucket
  key    = each.value.key
  source = each.value.source
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks that worked. Still learning TF so this is very helpful @Marcin